# Can I use the WeDo USB hub with normal Linux distributions?

Tags: wedo

I haven't found a lot of detail on the [WeDo USB hub](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=33718&in=S).  Is this device usable with Linux?  I found [one article](http://www.olpcnews.com/software/third_party/lego_mindstorms_nxt_xo_laptop.html) that indicated the OLPC XO had support for it, but it implied there was custom support added for that particular system.  And [this ad](http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/pub/p/id/596) implies it will work with Linux.

Has anyone used this with a regular Linux distribution?

Comment: Is this a questions for [super user](http://superuser.com/) ?

Comment: No, I'd say Unix/Linux, Ask Ubuntu, or here, and this seems like the most on-topic place.. If we're going to absorb Mindstorms we need to support questions like this. But I don't think we need a `linux` tag.

Comment: @JeoWreschnig: I don't think the Mindstorms tag is appropriate for this question; WeDo appears to be completely independent from Mindstorms.

Comment: @retracile, you raise a good point. From this post that I came across (http://www.welltrainedmind.com/forums/showthread.php?t=261433), WeDo's relationship to Mindstorms is similar to Duplo's relationship to regular Legos.

Comment: I'm using the LEGO WEDO HUB with pure JAVA controlling the USB (Linux, Mac, Win), if someone is interested please write back

Comment: Yes please.  A link to sources would also be useful...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lego's [education catalog](http://aux.legoeducation.us/sharedimages/PDF/Catalog/2011LEGOEducationMain.pdf) implies that the WeDo software is required for the hub to work. It states:

> The two-port hub controls motors and sensors, transmits power and data
>   to and from the computer, and is automatically detected by the WeDo™
>   Software when connected to the computer.

I found some info regarding WeDo software, the [manual](http://ro-botica.com/img/WeDo/pdf/WeDo_FAQ_new_2010.pdf) has this to say:

> **Q**: What is the full detailed information on the compatibility with different platforms?
>
> **A**: The WeDo™ software 1.1 is supported on Windows XP and Vista operating systems with the latest service packs. It is also supported
>   on the Mac 10.5.xx operating system with Mac Intel processors. A
>   minimum of 512 MB Ram is required and 300 MB of hard disc space. The
>   WeDo software 1.2 is supported on Windows XP, Vista and Windows 7
>   operating systems with the latest service packs, as well as the Mac
>   10.5.xx and Mac 10.6.xx operating systems with Mac Intel processors.

In general, Lego software seems to be supported only on OS X and Windows XP, Vista, and 7. All of the software mentioned in the Lego catalog (Lego Mindstorm Education NXT Software) indicated support for OS X 10.4 or later, and Windows XP, Vista, and 7. Linux support was not mentioned.

Comment: The hub doesn't have any intelligence on its own and so can't work independently. It doesn't even have a power source, as a matter of fact. To be honest, compared to the NXT, is seems a bit pointless, but I suppose it's a good start for kids.

Answer (score 3):

You can use WeDo with MIT Scratch 1.4 according to http://info.scratch.mit.edu/WeDo, and Scratch runs on Linux- and this thread https://lists.launchpad.net/scratch/msg00269.html indicates that the Linux Scratch does work with WeDo.

Answer (score 1):

I've just discover that the WEDO USB Hub just send to the motors 5V instead of 9V, so that's stopping me for doing a lot of stuff. Does anybody know how to add a separate source power and only send and read data from the USB Hub?

Comment: I think this would be better posted as its own question, rather than as an answer here...

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I have recently found that the LEGO WeDo hub connection works just fine on the Raspbian distro that comes with a Raspberry Pi, but it's not working on an Ubermix (Ubuntu) distro that I put on some Dell laptops.

See my post on this at http://scratched.media.mit.edu/discussions/bugs-troubleshooting-suggestions/scratch-wedo-linux-distro-specific-issues .